# get the latest line using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a file with a format similar to this:

```
10:26:50 AEYTCVAETK     2   genes ADUm.1024,ADUm.5198,ADUm.750
10:27:51 AIQLTGK        1   genes ADUm.1999,ADUm.3560
10:35:12 AIQLTGK        8   genes ADUm.1999,ADUm.3560
10:42:26 AEYTCVAETK     2   genes ADUm.1024,ADUm.5198,ADUm.750
10:50:43 KHEPPTEVDIEGR  5   genes ADUm.367
10:52:23 VSSILEDKTT     9   genes ADUm.1192,ADUm.2731
10:52:26 AIQLTGK        10  genes ADUm.1999,ADUm.3560
10:55:16 VSSILEDKILSR   3   genes ADUm.2146,ADUm.5750
10:55:58 VSSILEDKILSR   2   genes ADUm.2146,ADUm.5750
```

I would like to print latest line for each distinct value of the name in column 2, meaning the above input would become:

```
10:42:26 AEYTCVAETK     2   genes ADUm.1024,ADUm.5198,ADUm.750
10:52:26 AIQLTGK        10  genes ADUm.1999,ADUm.3560
10:50:43 KHEPPTEVDIEGR  5   genes ADUm.367
10:52:23 VSSILEDKTT     9   genes ADUm.1192,ADUm.2731
10:55:58 VSSILEDKILSR   2   genes ADUm.2146,ADUm.5750
```

How can I do this ?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: is the file sorted by time already or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using awk if the file has been sorted by time.

```
awk '{a[$2]=$0}END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' file|sort -n

10:42:26 AEYTCVAETK     2   genes ADUm.1024,ADUm.5198,ADUm.750
10:50:43 KHEPPTEVDIEGR  5   genes ADUm.367
10:52:23 VSSILEDKTT     9   genes ADUm.1192,ADUm.2731
10:52:26 AIQLTGK        10  genes ADUm.1999,ADUm.3560
10:55:58 VSSILEDKILSR   2   genes ADUm.2146,ADUm.5750
```

If the original file is not sorted, run this :

```
awk '{s=$1;gsub(/:/,"",s);if (s>max[$2]){max[$2]=s;l[$2]=$0}}END{for (i in max) print l[i]}' file|sort -n
```

Comment: Thank you I was doing this, but instead of `print a[i]`, I was doing only `print i` for which I was getting only second column, let me test this and I will sure accept the answer :)
but why are you using sort -n ?